# How to construct this non-geometric mod $p$ Galois representation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations

Let $ K $ be a totally real cubic field. I am concerned with the following kind of Inverse Galois Problem:

> Is there a prime $ p>5 $ and a continuous representation $ \bar{\rho}:G_{K}\to {\rm
> GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p}) $ of the absolute Galois group $G_K$ of $K$
> such that
>
> 1. $ \bar{\rho} $ is unramified at any prime of $ K $ above $ p $;
> 2. $ \bar{\rho} $ is full, i.e. the image of $ \bar{\rho} $ contains $ {\rm SL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p}) $;
> 3. Recall that $ G_{K} $ has only three elements of finite order up to conjugacy which are the complex conjugations corresponding to the
>    real primes of $ K $. We ask that the determinants of the images of
>    these three elements are $ -1,-1 $ and $ 1 $, respectively.

A natural idea is to consider the representations of $ G_{\mathbb{Q}} $ first and then get the representations of $G_K$ by restriction, but such a representation would not satisfy condition 3. Moreover, the mod $p$ Galois representations  come from elliptic curves (or even algebraic geometry, i.e. a subquotient of an etale cohomology group of some algebraic variety over $K$) should never satisfy the above requirements. Also, if such $ \bar{\rho} $ exists, then the defining polynomial of the splitting field of $ \bar{\rho} $ is at least greater than $5$. For these reasons, I don't know how to construct such a representation. Or is it possible to use some kind of computer software like [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Overview/overview.html) to get an example?

Any comments and reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you already know this, but it follows easily from a theorem of Moret-Bailly in "Extensions de corps globaux à ramification et groupe de Galois donnés" that there do exist totally real fields $K$ (whose degree is not specified) and representations $\bar{\rho}$ of $G_K$ satisfying 1, 2 and also a version of 3 where say $2/3$ of the complex conjugations have determinant $-1$ and $1/3$ have determinant $1$.

Comment: @naf Thanks a lot for your reference. If I understand correctly,  for any fixed finite group $G$, you mean taking $K=\mathbb{Q},\sum=\{\infty\}$ in Theorem 1.2 of the article, then we obtain a totall real number field $E$ and a finite Galois extension $F/E$ with group $G$  which is unramified elsewhere. But how to ensure it satisfies 3? For example,  what do you mean $2/3$ or $1/3$? It seems that we don't know if the degree of $E$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: You can start with any $K$, so you can take it to be a real cubic field and for the three infinite places take elements as in your 3. Then $E$ is an extension of $K$ so will have degree divisible by three. Of course, many variants are possible.

Comment: @naf Yes, you are right.